Can I have a dynamic scale for a CustomField?
I have a custom field which is type currency. I would like to know if it is possible to change the scale based on what type of precision I would like, or do I need to create separate fields for each decimal value of precision.
For example if I have $1 (scale of 0 )vs $1.1 (scale of 1) vs $1.0001 (scale of 4).
Can I have the same custom field used for each or do I need a new custom field depending on the decimal precision I need.

Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Have you considered using a single Currency input field with the highest precision and then formula Currency fields with the lower precisions?

The direct answer to the question is "No, you can't. Currency precision is static." Perhaps it may be better to go into what your motivation here is. Why are you looking to have multiple precisions? What does that help you achieve?

No you can't you. Because the when you are creating the currency field, you also setup how many decimal place it should have.
